# Load from Bokeh HTML file and overlay other shapes?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I have a Bokeh HTML file. I want to load it into a python program and overlay another shape, say a circle on it.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is not any good way to do this.

Once you have exported Bokeh to HTML, it's not in a form that can be further manipulated. If you extract the Bokeh JSON payload in side the HTML you could *in principal* do "surgery" on it to insert new JSON for additional glyphs. But this would be *incredibly fragile*, highly dependent on matched version and probably hacked object IDs to avoid ID collisions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Will remain open for a few days to see if other answers come. If not, will accept yours

Comment: I'll write a feature request under Bokeh's GitHub page

Comment: I'm a Bokeh core dev. It's not likely to be something we can add. Our only options would be the same terrible ones I listed above. HTML is a one-way export.

Comment: Cool! Could we obtain the file in another format? I don't need to read and interact with the file per se. I just need to store the output and be able to load it back from another program